# GMail SMTP does not authorize the credentials used in JavaMail API- even though they are correct

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have written a test code to send email from may Java App. Even though I am using a valid gmail address and the password, I get the following error when I run the test code:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

And here is my test code

```
public class GmailSmtpSSL {

    GmailSmtpSSL(String username, String password) {
        usern = username;
        pass = password;

        setDebugMsg("Setting user name to : " + usern);
        setDebugMsg("Using given password : " + pass);

        props = new Properties();
        setDebugMsg("Setting smtp server: smtp.gmail.com");
        setDebugMsg("Using SSL at port 465 auth enabled");

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", usern);

        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        SMTPAuthenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(true);
        setDebugMsg("Session initialization complete");
    }

    public void destroy() {
        props.clear();
        props = null;
        usern = null;
        pass = null;
        session = null;

    }

    public void sendMailTo(String to, String sub, String body)
            throws MessagingException {

        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a");
        String dateToday = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).toLowerCase();

        if (to.equals("self")) {
            to = usern;
        }

        setDebugMsg("Composing message: To " + to);
        setDebugMsg("Composing message: Subject " + sub);

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(usern));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject("PinguBot: " + dateToday + " " + sub);
            message.setText(body);
            setDebugMsg("Attempting to send...");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");

            transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, usern, pass);
            Transport.send(message);
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException me) {
            setDebugMsg(me.toString());
            throw new MessagingException(me.toString());
        }
        setDebugMsg("Mail was send successfully");
    }

    public String getDebugMsg() {
        String msg = new String(debugMsg);
        debugMsg = " ";
        return msg;
    }

    private static void setDebugMsg(String msg) {
        debugMsg += msg + "\n";
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    private static String debugMsg = "";
    private String usern;
    private String pass;
    private Session session;
    private static Properties props;

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(usern, pass);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        GmailSmtpSSL gssl=new GmailSmtpSSL("<valid Id>@gmail.com", "<valid password>");
        String to="satinder_2000@outlook.com";
        String sub="Hello";
        String body= "Hamara Dil Aapke Paas hai!!";

        try {
            gssl.sendMailTo(to, sub, body);
        } catch (MessagingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GmailSmtpSSL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Instead, I receive an email in my gmail inbox as follows

Sub - Critical security alert

Body - Someone just used your password to try to sign in to your account from a non-Google app. Google blocked them, but you should check what happened. Review your account activity to make sure no one else has access.

Could someone please advise what could be wrong with the code?

Appreciate any help!

Regards

Singham

Comment: You're not dong anything wrong. It is Google and the way they handle apps sending emails. Please check this article to see if it helps you. I ran into the same problems.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization

Comment: **Log in** to your account, go to your **Security** settings and turn on **Allow less secure apps**.

Comment: You may also need to create an [app-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en).  And you might want to fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).